# How can I combine img() function and unlink() to delete images

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, delete-file

In CodeIgniter I use the build-in function `img()`, that takes `http://` path to the images, but when I delete the record and then delete the image by `unlink()` - I have an error that say's "not allowed to delete by http", how can I combine these two function to work?

Comment: Please only ask one question at once, I've removed the second question from your answer so far.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP-URLs are not supported for [`unlink()`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/unlink), that's why you get the error message (there is a [HTTP `DELETE` method<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.7), however it's not commonly supported, so this has not been introduced to `unlink` and the [HTTP Stream Wrapper<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php)).

So just don't use `unlink()` for HTTP-URLs because HTTP does not support deletion of files, you can replace the HTTP wrapper with your own that does offer `unlink` support (or just skips/nulls the command w/o notice) if you really need to use `unlink`.

Comment: and what function i need to use to do the delete in php??

Comment: There is no way to delete HTTP-URLs in PHP (Generally there is no standardized way to delete HTTP-URLs as well. That's why there isn't one in PHP).

Comment: what if i create one more column to write system path for deleting?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but this might help you

```
function delete_data($record_id)
{
    $query =  $this->db->get_where('projukti_committee',array('record_id' => $record_id));
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $row = $query->row();
        $picture = $row->picture;
        unlink(realpath('assets/photo/'.$picture));
        $this->db->delete('projukti_committee', array('record_id' => $record_id));
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: the $picture has a http:// prefix??, just tried it like this echo realpath($q->image); - the output is empty